# Redux how to set initial state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, state

I'm working on a project which contains React, Redux and TypeScript.

I can't figure out how to set the initial state because of the type restrictions of TypeScript. Does someone know how to set the types?

I've compressed everything in one file for simplicity, and will be divided in to separate files later on.

**state/index.ts**

```
import { Notes } from '@material-ui/icons'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'

// Types
type Note = {
    title: string
    description: string
}

type NoteState = {
    notes: Array<Note>
}

type NoteAction = {
    type: string
    payload: Note
}

type CountState = {
    count: number
}

type CountAction = {
    type: string
    payload: number
}

// Actions
const ADD_NOTE = 'ADD_NOTE'
const addNote: (note: Note) => NoteAction = (n) => ({ type: ADD_NOTE, payload: n })

const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'
const increment: (n: number) => CountAction = (n) => ({ type: INCREMENT, payload: n + 1 })

// Reducer
const noteReducer: (s: NoteState, a: NoteAction) => NoteState = (s = { notes: [] }, a) => {
    switch (a.type) {
        case ADD_NOTE:
            return { notes: [...s.notes, a.payload] }
        default:
            return s
    }
}

const countReducer: (s: CountState, a: CountAction) => CountState = (s = { count: 0 }, a) => {
    switch (a.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return { count: a.payload }
        default:
            return s
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    notes: noteReducer,
    counter: countReducer,
})

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

// Store
const state = createStore(rootReducer({ notes: [], counter: 0 }, null))
```

**Error**
When initializing the state object, the IDE gives the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<unknown, Action<any>>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, unknown> | undefined): Store<unknown, Action<any>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'CombinedState<{ notes: never; counter: never; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<unknown, Action<any>>'.
      Type 'CombinedState<{ notes: never; counter: never; }>' provides no match for the signature '(state: unknown, action: Action<any>): unknown'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<unknown, Action<any>>, preloadedState?: {} | undefined, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, {}> | undefined): Store<unknown, Action<any>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'CombinedState<{ notes: never; counter: never; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<unknown, Action<any>>'.ts(2769)
```

I need to set the App State in the createStore function. Because later, there will be a function retrieving the App State from local storage and pass it through the createStore method. But I want to make this work first. Does anyone have experience with Redux + TypeScript?

Comment: Can you try, const initialData: RootState  = { notes: [], counter: 0 };

const state = createStore(rootReducer(initialData), null))

Comment: I think, You should not pass any data to rootReducer.

Comment: const initialData: RootState = { notes: [], counter: 0 }; const state = createStore(rootReducer)

Comment: I tried, but I get an error which I don't understand yet. It has to do with the IDE complaining about the value inside InitialData being type ```never```.

```Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
index.ts(55, 5): The expected type comes from property 'notes' which is declared here on type 'CombinedState<{ notes: never; counter: never; }>'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you put the wrong arguments for `createStore` function. It would take `rootReducer` as the 1st argument, initial state as the 2nd argument but you set the result of the call your `rootReducer` as the 1st argument. Just change it right as following:

```js
interface AppState {
  notes: NoteState;
  counter: CountState;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers<AppState>({
  notes: noteReducer,
  counter: countReducer
});

const state = createStore(rootReducer, {
  notes: { notes: [] },
  counter: {
    count: 0
  }
});
```

One more thing to notice, the 1st state parameter is likely undefined so you have to set it can be `undefined`:

```js
const noteReducer: (s: NoteState | undefined, a: NoteAction) => NoteState = (
```

NOTE: Here is the codesandbox for you to mess around: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sound-0lh92?file=/src/store.ts:1178-1276

Comment: I tried this too, but I still get an error which you can also see in the codesandbox you've created. The IDE is complaining about the ```notes```.

Comment: I dropped you another hint regarding the state can be undefined